# ConcurrentModificationException when updating a ListView that extends an ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView that has an adapter for each cell. This adapter extends ArrayAdapter (my object class).
The app also has 2 tabs so far. Tab 1 has the list, Tab 2 has a map.

Each cell in the adapter has a check box, which by default is unchecked.

The issue I have is that when I switch tabs the checked boxes return to be unchecked, and if I iterate an array of checked boxes, I get a ConcurrentModificationException when I try to mark a box as checked.

Here's my code of what I'm doing:

```
    value_checkBox.setTag(route.getRouteShortName());

    value_checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isChecked == true)
            {
                RouteListLV.arrayOfRoutesEnabled.add(route);
            }
            else
            {
                RouteListLV.arrayOfRoutesEnabled.remove(route);
            }
        }
    });
```

This part (the sample code above) works, and here's where I am adding the checked routes into a static array that can be used by multiple views.

```
    for (Route routeFromArray : RouteListLV.arrayOfRoutesEnabled)
    {
        if (routeFromArray.getRouteShortName().equals(route.getRouteShortName() ) )
        {
            System.out.println("Match!");
            value_checkBox.setChecked(true);    <--- causes the ConcurrentModificationException
        }
    }
```

This loop (the for loop above) doesn't work and the exception happens when I set the checkBox to be checked.
I have tried an iterator as well, but I get the same result:

```
    Iterator<Route> iterator = RouteListLV.arrayOfRoutesEnabled.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        Route routeFromArray = iterator.next();

        if (routeFromArray.getRouteShortName().equals(route.getRouteShortName() ) )
        {
            System.out.println("Match!");
            value_checkBox.setChecked(true);    <--- causes the ConcurrentModificationException
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on this issue?
Just to be clear, I have 2 arrayLists. One is the one with the entire list of "routes" which is being passed to the ArrayAdapter to form the list, and I have a second arrayList for just the selected routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating through an `ArrayList` (`RouteListLV.arrayOfRoutesEnabled`) and modifying it as you go along.  That causes a `ConcurrentModificationException`, so don't do it.  Find a way to first find the element or elements you're going to modify and then modify the list (and never use the iterator after that).  Or build a "shadow" copy of the list that has everything you want it to have at the end, then call `removeAll()` and then `addAll(newList)` on the original list, which is just that same idea in a slightly different form.

Comment: But the exception is not being thrown when I add or remove routes from the arrayList, like in here:                     RouteListLV.arrayOfRoutesEnabled.add(route);

The exception is only being thrown when I want to modify the value of the checkbox, with the elements of the already modified arrayList.

Comment: Changing the value of the checkbox calls `RouteListLV.arrayOfRoutesEnabled.add(route)`; how do you think that "the exception is not being thrown when I add or rmeove routes from the ArrayList?  Seems like that's exactly what you're doing...

Comment: Also, what makes you say you have an "already modified ArrayList"?  I don't see any code that does that.

Comment: You were right. Making a copy of the arrayList and calling it before setting the listener on the check box did the trick.
Thanks!